# asynchronous call from UnitTest in C#

Tags: c#, wcf, asynchronous, unit-testing

Need a quick help -

I need to build a testcase, which calls the service asynchornously , the service operation performs its actions (the actions performed by service takes lot of time)
The TestCase should wait for the service response and after recieveing the response it should put all the results in excel.

currently i have created a service and called it asynchornously from Testcase, but the problem is that the service timesout, so does timeout matters if i call the service operation asynchornously and is there any other alternative method for the above implementation.

thanx in advance

Comment: The question is not clear. You say the service time out, do you mean that your test code ends up with an exception? If so, doesn't this suggest you may need to either speed up that service, or increase the timeout value?

Comment: This is not a *unit* test - let's be very clear about that. The timeout sounds to me like a problem with the service you have created and nothing to do with the test.

Comment: thnx for ur interest, no the testcase doesnot ends with an exception, actually the service performs the validation of data in DB and gives the results of the validation done( the validation of data takes a lot of time) 1- does the testcase not wait till the service operation is completed

Answer (score 1):

For the unit test case , to test the code which is calling webservice make use of **STUB(its stub of webservice)** rather than making actual call

and create seprate test cases to test you webservice method.

Testing with webservice is part of integration testing not part of unit testing.